# Why can´t I insert html in a nested div via Javascript?

Tags: javascript, fetch, innerhtml

I am working with the Nasa Insight API.
Why cant I insert the "innerHtml" into the "div.temp"? 
The innerHtml with the "div.sol" works fine, but the "div.temp" does not... Please help!

```js
async function getMarsWeather() {
  const url = 'https://api.nasa.gov/insight_weather/?api_key= lYQZM29QeEW8Oe7Vjp7eYRna8ftZfK10JHVjqmma&feedtype=json&ver=1.0';

  return await (await fetch(url)).json();
}

function paintMarsData(marsData) {
  const sol = document.querySelectorAll('.sol');
  const temp = document.querySelectorAll('.temp');

  sol.forEach((sol, index) => sol.textContent = `Sol: ${ marsData.sol_keys[index] }`);
  temp.forEach((temp, index) => temp.innerHTML = `test ${ index }`);
}

getMarsWeather().then(paintMarsData);
```

```html
<h1>Weather on Mars at Elysium Planitia</h1>

<div id="mars_weather">
    <div class="sol"><div class="temp"></div></div>
    <div class="sol"><div class="temp"></div></div>
    <div class="sol"><div class="temp"></div></div>
    <div class="sol"><div class="temp"></div></div>
    <div class="sol"><div class="temp"></div></div>
    <div class="sol"><div class="temp"></div></div>
    <div class="sol"><div class="temp"></div></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Setting `.textContent` of those `.sol`s will remove (overwrite) the inner `.temp` divs.

Comment: Thanks! How can I get around that problem?

Comment: Lots of ways. Any ideas?

Comment: Ok! Some examples?

Comment: I could dynamically insert all the html via javascript..

Comment: Yes, or you can put two inner divs in each wrapper div and set the texts of those two.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can recreate "temp" divs when writing to "sol"

```js
function paintMarsData(marsData) {
  const sol = document.querySelectorAll('.sol');
  sol.forEach((sol, index) => sol.innerHTML = `Sol: ${ marsData.sol_keys[index] }<div class="temp"></div>`);

  const temp = document.querySelectorAll('.temp');
  temp.forEach((temp, index) => temp.innerHTML = `test ${ index }`);
}

//getMarsWeather().then(paintMarsData);
paintMarsData({ sol_keys: [1, 2, 3, 'z'] })
```

```html
<h1>Weather on Mars at Elysium Planitia</h1>

<div id="mars_weather">
    <div class="sol"><div class="temp"></div></div>
    <div class="sol"><div class="temp"></div></div>
    <div class="sol"><div class="temp"></div></div>
    <div class="sol"><div class="temp"></div></div>
    <div class="sol"><div class="temp"></div></div>
    <div class="sol"><div class="temp"></div></div>
    <div class="sol"><div class="temp"></div></div>
</div>
```

Or you can recreate parent block's content each time

```js
function paintMarsData(marsData) {
  const div = document.getElementById('mars_weather');
  div.innerHTML = marsData.sol_keys.map((sol, index) => `<div class="sol">
        Sol: ${ sol } <div class="temp">test ${ index }</div>
  </div>`).join('')
}

//getMarsWeather().then(paintMarsData);
paintMarsData({ sol_keys: [1, 2, 3, 'z'] });
```

```html
<h1>Weather on Mars at Elysium Planitia</h1>

<div id="mars_weather"></div>
```